# Why did Baudrillard regard 'terrorism as fashion and the media'?

Tags: postmodernism

[*Understand Postmodernism: A Teach Yourself Guide*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071419659).  Glenn Ward [BA in fine art (painting), University of Plymouth, 1990;  MA in Visual Culture, Bath Spa University, 1992; PhD in film studies, University of Sussex, 2011.](http://arts.brighton.ac.uk/staff/glenn-ward)
p. 91.

> On Planet Baudrillard, the distinction between simulation and reality has collapsed. In *The Evil Demon of Images*, he calls this a telescoping or **implosion** of image into reality. We hinted at some of the ways in which this has happened when we noted how images intersect with (and, we might add, enable) certain experiences of the world. It will not surprise you to learn that Baudrillard goes a lot further than this simple observation. In fact, he turns conventional thinking about the ‘logical order of the real and its reproduction’ inside out, so that images do not just intersect with the real; they precede it, anticipate it, absorb it and produce it. Even with the examples given above, Baudrillard would claim that reality was an ‘effect’ of representation. He makes this point rather dramatically in a passage from his travelogue *America* (1988, first published in France 1986):
>
> > Everything is destined to reappear as simulation. Landscapes as photography, women as the sexual scenario, thoughts as writing, **terrorism as fashion and the media [my emboldening]**. Things seem only to exist by virtue of this strange destiny. You wonder whether the world itself isn’t just here to serve as advertising copy in some other world.

Plsease see my emboldening, which sounds so overblown as to be unbelievable?

Comment: Capitalism can recoup anything. Anything can be made into a T shirt to sell no matter how horrible or in bad taste it is. Background: study Situationists. In principle, any horror can be marketed. Why? Because there are no principles except to sell something. So everything that happens now is for advertising copy.  We are not so much interested in what happens, as we are in how to make a dollar off it.  And the media itself gets the first crack at exploiting the event for money. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situationist_International

Comment: The actual event is almost unimportant, rather the focus is on what can be done with it.

Comment: this is a philosophy forum, not an art forum. Post modern art should not be confused with post modern philosophy.